# Failing a unit test with an exception

Tags: r, unit-testing

In svUnit, the `checkException` (documentation [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svUnit/svUnit.pdf)) function will pass if the `expr` generates an exception when run.

This seems very counter-intuitive. If your code operates as expected, it won't generate an exception and will therefore fail the test. However, in the case of `checkEquals`, your code operating correctly will pass the test, as expected.

Why does `checkException` cause a test to fail when the code operates as expected, but the rest of the `check` functions do the opposite? Also, is there a function that behaves like `checkException` but does the opposite?

Comment: There are times when you want to throw an exception. One scenario may be if you had a web service which received user input and supplied a result. You may have a global handler which handles some "InvalidParameter" exception by creating an error response explaining which parameter is invalid and why. In this case, you may wish to test that supplying an invalid parameter does in fact throw an exception.

Comment: How else would you check if your code fails when it is supposed to fail?

Comment: You are wrong when you say *If your code operates as expected, it won't generate an exception [...]*. When I run `log("a")` it throws an error and that's what I expect of it. So running `checkException(log("a"))` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Also, while I can't speak specifically to svUnit, any test that generates an exception which does not expect and check for that exception should fail. checkException should be the opposite of the default behavior -- a test that does nothing but throw an exception without checking for it should fail.